# How to check programmatically that source compiles?

Tags: c++

There is some string with code:

```
std::string code = "int main(){return 0;}"
```

What tool can I use to check whether this is valid C++ code? Something similar to

```
checker.checkCPPcode(code) which returns bool
```

would be nice.

Comment: A compiler, what else?

Comment: Why not write it to a temporary file, run the normal C++ compiler on it, and check the return code?

Comment: [Library to parse C/C++ source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318347/library-to-parse-c-c-source-code)

Comment: @Sjoerd: Parsing is not sufficient to tell whether code compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A C++ compiler like `g++` will do the job. Write the string into a temporary file, run `g++ -fsyntax-only` on the file, and act on the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You can paste the content of the string in a newly created `cpp` file and run `g++` or whatever compiler you can use on it and check the compiler's output.